# Can I use a dynamic value to access a specific array in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, dynamic-values

I've been trying to figure out how to do this, but can't seem to get it to work. I have created a function that is being called when I click a component using v-on:click. I am also trying to pass in a value that I can then use to access a particular array that is coming in the form of data from a backend.

Here is the function in the component:

```
<v-card
  @click="getContent('topSellers')"
 >
```

I am then passing the 'topSellers' value as an "id" into the function that is being used to get access the exact array that I am looking for:

```
getContent(id) {
      this.accordion = this.data.id;
      console.log("data", id);
    }
```

First of all, `this.data.topSellers` works. And I am seeing that the id value is correct in the console. Obviously, this is not working because id is currently a string, but I don't know how to fix that issue. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the entire code? it is ambiguous

Comment: `this.accordion = this.data[id]` Absolut basics...

Answer (score 0):

You need `this.data[id]` instead of `this.data.id`.

See [property accessors on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) for reference.

`data[id]` will access the property of `data` with the **name** of the **value** of `id`, in your case `topSellers`. So `data.topSellers` is equivalent to `data["topSellers"]`

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate the help.

Comment: how about row.item['user.name'] not work ? row.item[`${dynamic_key}`] ,

Answer (score 0):

[] allows you to access objects with variables.

It is recommended to handle exceptions because the variable received is not safe.

```
getContent(id) {
  const accordion = this.data[id] || null;
  if(accordion){
    console.log("data", accordion);
    this.accordion = accordion;
  }
}
```